# SQL LIMIT to get latest records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, limit, greatest-n-per-group

I am writing a script which will list 25 items of all 12 categories. Database structure is like:

```
tbl_items
---------------------------------------------
item_id | item_name | item_value | timestamp 
---------------------------------------------

tbl_categories
-----------------------------
cat_id | item_id | timestamp
-----------------------------
```

There are around 600,000 rows in the table `tbl_items`. I am using this SQL query:

```
SELECT e.item_id, e.item_value
  FROM tbl_items AS e
  JOIN tbl_categories AS cat WHERE e.item_id = cat.item_id AND cat.cat_id = 6001
  LIMIT 25
```

Using the same query in a loop for `cat_id` from 6000 to 6012. But I want the latest records of every category. If I use something like:

```
SELECT e.item_id, e.item_value
  FROM tbl_items AS e
  JOIN tbl_categories AS cat WHERE e.item_id = cat.item_id AND cat.cat_id = 6001
  ORDER BY e.timestamp
  LIMIT 25
```

..the query goes computing for approximately 10 minutes which is not acceptable. Can I use `LIMIT` more nicely to give the latest 25 records for each category?

Can anyone help me achieve this without `ORDER BY`? Any ideas or help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
tbl_items

+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| item_id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| item_name           | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| item_value          | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp           | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

tbl_categories

+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cat_id         | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| item_id        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| timestamp      | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Please show your table create statements. Are your indexes correct?

Comment: @Astha - Please can you confirm what indexes you have, and whether you can request/create new ones?

Comment: It is not clear from the question whether the whole result should be ordered by timestamp or data within each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

It seems to be a N:M relation between `items` and `categories`: a `item` may be in several `categories`. I say this because `categories` has `item_id` foreign key.

If is not a N:M relationship then you should consider to change design. If it is a 1:N relationship, where a category has several items, then `item` must constain `category_id` foreign key.

Working with N:M:

I have rewrite your query to make a inner join insteat a cross join:

```
  SELECT e.item_id, e.item_value
  FROM 
     tbl_items AS e
  JOIN 
     tbl_categories AS cat 
        on e.item_id = cat.item_id
  WHERE  
     cat.cat_id = 6001
  ORDER BY 
     e.timestamp
  LIMIT 25
```

To optimize performance required indexes are:

```
create index idx_1 on tbl_categories( cat_id, item_id)
```

it is not mandatory an index on items because primary key is also indexed.
A index that contains timestamp don't help as mutch. To be sure can try with an index on item with `item_id` and `timestamp` to avoid access to table and take values from index:

```
create index idx_2 on tbl_items( item_id, timestamp)
```

To increase performace you can change your loop over categories by a single query:

```
  select T.cat_id, T.item_id, T.item_value from 
  (SELECT cat.cat_id, e.item_id, e.item_value
   FROM 
     tbl_items AS e
   JOIN 
     tbl_categories AS cat 
        on e.item_id = cat.item_id
   ORDER BY 
     e.timestamp
   LIMIT 25
  ) T
  WHERE  
     T.cat_id between 6001 and 6012
  ORDER BY
     T.cat_id, T.item_id
```

Please, try this querys and come back with your comments to refine it if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I cannot change the structure of the db as its not mine. but yes it is 1:N relation tables. one item_id will be only in one category. I tried this query but its also taking same amount of time. i am using a loop for the category ids a i can't use single query like this with between caluse. hope you got my point.

Comment: If is not your database they are not a easy solution. Take a look to this related question: [Is cross-table indexing possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509026/is-cross-table-indexing-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Can you add indices? If you add an index on the `timestamp` and other appropriate columns the `ORDER BY` won't take 10 minutes.

Comment: An index is like a phone book. If there were no order in a phone book, it would take hours to look up someone's phone number. An index on the timestamp column tells MySQL where the records are located, *by timestamp* so it can look up rows like you would in a phonebook.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any decent websites to get you started. (anyone?)

Comment: Well, there's always the official documentation although it might not be the best introduction to the subject: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Yup, no indices on the timestamp column. Adding an index on the timestamp column of the items table will speed up your `ORDER BY` by a factor of thousands (and I am not exaggerating).

Comment: Use a B-Tree it's a ordered index. Hash Index is not ordered.

Comment: This may be daunting if you're just starting out (it was for me) but you can learn a lot. If you run a query that looks like `EXPLAIN {sql-query}` then MySQL will tell you how it would execute `{sql-query}`.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Exactly, have a column created_at, while selecting from it just `ORDER BY 'created_at' DESC LIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside all other factors I can tell you that the main reason why the query is so slow, is because the result involves `longtext` columns.

`BLOB` and `TEXT` fields in MySQL are mostly meant to store complete files, textual or binary. They are stored separately from the row data for InnoDB tables. Each time a query involes sorting (explicitly or for a `group by`), MySQL is sure to use disk for the sorting (because it can not be sure in advance how large any file is).

And it is probably a rule of thumb: if you need to return more than a single row of a column in a query, the type of the field is almost never should be `TEXT` or `BLOB`, use `VARCHAR` or `VARBINARY` instead.

**UPD**

If you can not update the table, the query will hardly be fast with the current indexes and column types. But, anyway, here is a similar question and a popular solution to your problem: [How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Really appreciated but as i told this database is not mine. I only have to fetch data to show.