# SQL optimization to get random Row

Tags: mysql

I am using

```
SELECT * 
  FROM picture 
 INNER JOIN user ON picture.fbid = user.fbid 
 WHERE hide = 0 
   AND userhide = 0 
 ORDER BY gender, RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This executes and gives me the link to a picture of a random row where the gender is female. It takes around 15 seconds to execute.

How could I change the SQL so that it is calculated fast? Should I add a gender column in the Picture table  so that it doesn't combine both the table and then gets a random row or is there some other way to optimise the SQL?

Comment: Why is this tagged `[mysql]` and `[sql-server]`? Which is it and what indexes do you have and what is the current explain plan?

Comment: BTW, there's no guarantee that the row returned will have the gender as female... You would need `and user.gender = 'female'` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Ben - Yeah , But since it orders it with females first so it kind of worked . Ya the SQL is not  perfect and it takes a lot of time to execute

Comment: http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EDIT]** You can do the same with a MySQL stored procedure, I just coded it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0e6a/2

(Note: Not having the count done in every query would aliviate the load, otherwise in this particular case it can be even slower and I would recommend to keep your query, but with index optimization. Or check this out: [Is cross-table indexing possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509026/is-cross-table-indexing-possible))

**[EDIT 2]** Here's another example with index optimization using an average of 50000 random entries in each table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfbe1/1 The query takes less than 100ms (Without indexes I left it running for several minutes and still no result!). You can create indexes on existing tables using [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Here's my solution using 2 queries from a PHP script:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM picture 
 INNER JOIN user ON picture.fbid = user.fbid 
 WHERE hide = 0 
   AND userhide = 0
   AND gender = 'female' 
   GROUP BY gender";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM picture 
      INNER JOIN user ON picture.fbid = user.fbid 
      WHERE hide = 0 
      AND userhide = 0
      AND gender = 'female' 
      LIMIT FLOOR(RAND()*$row['COUNT(*)']),1";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$picture=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This should make you query a lot faster.

Also, if your tables are big (which I guess it's the case, since the query takes 15 secs) it would help if the conditional/join fields are indexed.

Comment: added a solution as an stored procedure so you can avoid sending more than one query, check that out ;)

Comment: 50000 records in SQL Fiddle?  Gah! It's not for raw performance testing (since that is subject to many different variables); SQL Fiddle is supposed to help you craft the structure of your query, as a test case.  Relative performance can be judged by comparing execution plans.  I think I'm going to need to set a hard limit in the MySQL database size, to prevent things like this - it's just too hard on the servers, if everyone does it this way.

Comment: You're right, I'll keep that in mind. Anyway I've also made some "actual" RAW tests with uniformely distributed random records (about 50 million on each table) on a virtualbox (1 GHz 1 core, 1GB of RAM) on my laptop. Then I discovered the `count(*)` query + `limit floor(rand()*count),1` query is not much of an optimization in this case: It takes between 200 and 400 seconds to process on this virtualbox computer versus an stable 200 and something for the `order by rand()` solution, which I guess depends on how many records match the query (average of 3125000 in this case).

Comment: (Still I kept my answer for future edit where I will suggest to keep an estimated count to aliviate the load, but I don't know on which basis the first part of the stored procedure should be triggered to have the count updated. Any ideas?)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating an INDEX on `picture.fbid = user.fbid` this will help to speed the `JOIN` on the table.

More Mysql specific information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html