# Create multi-column index including column from related table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a model similar to the following:

```
Alert:
+ id : int
+ timestamp : datetime
+ message : text

UserAlert:
+ id : int
+ user_id : int, foreign key User.id
+ alert_id : int, foreign key Alert.id
+ archive : bool, default false
```

Basically, I'm creating alerts which are shared by multiple users (which users receive the alerts varies depending on the alert), but each user can "archive" each alert within his own alert inbox.

**The problem:** How do I give a particular user his newest non-archived alerts in a split second? ... or put more precisely, how do I create an **index** which runs the following query with optimum efficiency?

```
SELECT a.id, a.timestamp, a.message
FROM UserAlert AS ua
INNER JOIN Alert AS a
ON a.id = ua.alert_id
WHERE ua.user_id = 1234 and ua.archive = false
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Basically, I need an index on columns `(UserAlert.user_id, Alert.timestamp)`. But I don't know how to create an index which uses multiple columns from two or more related tables. Seems like it should be a common problem, but I don't know what words to look for on Google, and so here I am looking for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Isaac, you can use for below code, also you can search as composite index "CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON table_name(c2,c3,c4);" Related link https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/#:~:text=MySQL%20allows%20you%20to%20create,two%20columns%2C%20and%20so%20on.

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ The indexes created at your link are composed of multiple columns *from the same table*. I want to compose columns *from different tables* into one index.

Comment: I just found this related stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509026/is-cross-table-indexing-possible It looks like this is possible in SQLServer as Indexed Views, which is not supported in mysql, which is my target environment.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have an index that works across multiple tables.  (`VIEWs` don't help.)

The best that can be done is to use "covering" indexes.

```
ua:  INDEX(archive, user_id, alert_id)
a:  -- no recommendation assuming InnoDB and PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

If you could redundantly store the `timestamp` in `Alert`, then you could get 100 ids *before* reaching into the other table.  (Currently, it must look at *all* the Alerts for the user, sort them, then deliver 100.)